# Set different filenames to different loggers

Tags: python, debugging

Using this python code:

```
import logging
log1 = logging.getLogger("module1")
log2 = logging.getLogger("module2")
```

How can I set *log1* to be written to *fileName1* and *log2* to be written to *filename2* ? 
by default they both write to STDERR instead of files at all

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the relevant handler to each logger directly e.g.

`log1.addHandler(logging.handlers.FileHandler(fileName1)
log2.addHandler(logging.handlers.FileHandler(fileName1)`

You may need to set whatever formatter on these handlers.

Note that at this point, the messages sent to either logger will *still* be written to stderr: `logging` is a tree of handlers, logging records start at a "leaf" logger and are handled by each logger before being sent to its parent, until the root logger. Every single logger in the path might both print the message to some output (e.g. file, syslog, stream, …) *and* send it to its parent.

There are several options to avoid/configure/improve this behaviour:

- do nothing if that's fine (e.g. you want all logging to go to the default output, but some to be duplicated in other destinations)
- set these loggers to not propagate (`logger.propagate = False`), in which case the log records will "stop" at the relevant logger and not go up the tree any further
- set a `NullHandler` as handler to the root logger so it doesn't print the messages it receives (if a message reaches the root logger and it has no handler configured, a `StreamHandler(sys.stderr)` is automatically set on it), this allows all messages to reach the root logger and only be dropped *there*, which is convenient if you want to add further handlers in the future (e.g. send every logging message to the syslog at one point)
- disable the root logger entirely (`logging.getLogger().disabled = True`) but that's not really documented and a bit iffy